# How i can fix this warning org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError WARNING: Connection reset

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium4

I have updated my project from selenium 3 to 4 after that i am getting this warning after test execution completes.

```
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:401)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:434)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:256)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

I have these capabilities added:

```
`ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("window-size=1280x1024");
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability (ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        options.merge(capabilities);
        
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`
```

Also my POM is :

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <webdriver.driver>
e</webdriver.driver>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Cucumber report -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reports</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency> -->
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.